# Images not displaying from Assets

Tags: ios, xcode, image, xamarin, assets

I have a xamarin.ios (Using VS mac) project that I'm trying to add images to. I have 5 images and only two of the are loading. I have followed https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/ios/app-fundamentals/images-icons/displaying-an-image?tabs=macos for uploading images. It's weird cause the two images that are loading don't show up in the Assets folder when I open it up in Xcode but they do appear in finder. I'm not sure why I cant get the other three to appear..

[image]

[image]

"Coke" and "blt" are the only ones that show in the app, but they don't appear in the Assets in xcode.
I've made sure spelling and extension usage is all correct.
Any help would be great.

Comment: try to choose the folder and right click-->build action-->bundle resource

Comment: It seems there was a linking issue between VS mac and Xcode. So when I added the images to the Assets folder on Xcode it did not update the project file for some reason, though they would appear in finder in the Assets folder. I had to go into the project file and manually add them in.

Comment: what is your xcode&vs version? you can try to update them.